# Gas leaking from carburetor while ATV not running

Tags: carburetor, fuel-leak

I bought a Coolster (chinese) atv for my daughter and had to do some extensive work on it. But finally got it good as new, until today. I pulled the atv out of the shed for us to ride and started it. Ran fine for a minute then quit. Then I noticed a gas smell. So I looked at the carb, which is a PD24J for a 150cc GY6 engine, and found gas coming out of a tube that I'm certain it shouldn't be coming out of.

So my question is: What could be causing this & what do I need to do?

And its a new carburetor, but 90 day warranty has expired.

[image]

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! It seems like the float may be stuck, but I wouldn't know for sure. You could rap on the bowl area a few times with the butt of a screwdriver to see if the over feed stops. That wouldn't fix it permanently I'd bet.

Comment: Ok, thanks! I'll give it a try! If it comes down to it, I'll just get a rebuild kit and do that. May even find better jets for it.